# Обмен данными между Service (Android)

Tags: android, android-service

Как организовать обмен данными между Службами (`Service`) в ОС Android?

Answer (score 5):

Посылайте `Intent`'ы, это самый простой и понятный способ.

Есть способ хитрее: одна Служба подымает TCP сервер, а вторая к ней подключается. Но это уже немного извращение.